# Servlets that forward to JSPs

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, forward

I'm coding a Java EE WebApp which uses several JSP files. Until now, I use to write the addresses like this:

```
http://www.example.com/login.jsp
```

But I prefer they would be like:

```
http://www.example.com/login
```

So I made a Servlet for each JSP file, and they that look like this:

```
public class ForwardLoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                     throws ServletException, IOException {

        String url = context.getInitParameter("loginURL"); // this will return the login.jsp filename
        forwardToURL(url, request, response);
    }
    // More stuff here (doget, do post,...)
}
```

It works perfecty, but my question is: is there any another way to do this without creating a new Servlet for every JSP? It's not very fast to write a JSP an then write the Servlet for it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to map url to jsp then you can specify it in web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```